# I want to make an embedded Youtube video resizable by the user, while keeping the aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

Right now I am using the CSS `resize: both;` attribute to make a div around the video resizable. I want to limit the resizing available to the user, so that the div stays in its initial aspect ratio.

The end goal, is that the user can resize the YouTube video, but doesn't have to fiddle around to make sure there is no wasted space with black bars.

I looked into solutions that have a `padding-bottom` in an outer div, but as far as I can tell, these Solutions only work on resizing the browser, not on the `resize` css attribute.

I have looked into making the div resizable only in one direction, and then adjusting the other direction with Javascript. I looked into the `onresize` event, but it seems to be only working for resizing of the browser, not resizing with the `resize` css attribute. And if that would work, it would be more of a hack, and not the best user experience I imagine.

If the `resize` property is a bad idea anyway, I am open to other solutions that achieve my end goal.

Here is the code I want to make work like described:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

</style>

<body>

    <div id="mydiv">
        <iframe id="yt1" width ="100%"; height="100%"; src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/guf_FTQvjYA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>


<script> 

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

Comment: @Phix I don't think so, I found alot of answers talking about that trick, but if I understood everything correctly, it doesn't work with a resizable div, it only works when the whole window is resized.

Comment: @abielita I have not per se encountered an Error, because I am looking for a methodology. But you are right, I'll add some things I have tried. Thank you.